# target specific corners for rounding

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I have this shape and I want only the square corners to round. When I round the whole thing, it affects the circle part...

[image]

[image]

Comment: I dont' want to put this as answer since it's a purchase solution... but you may want to look into VectorScribe from wwww.astutegraphics.com - Its absolutely with the money.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [this script](http://dsmy2muqb7t4m.cloudfront.net/articles/2010/article_illustrator_plugin_scripts/scripts/RoundAnyCorner.zip) to round only the selected points.

It actually rounds the corners by drawing new points and curve handles, not like the Illustrator effect which can be adjusted at any time.

Comment: Hooray! Thank you. That worked perfectly. For those like me, web developers, you're probably going to just click this script and then read it all admire it - and then not know what to do. Select the points you want to round -> then from FILE->SCRIPTS->OTHER-SCRIPTS>choose the script. OR - If you are going to use it a lot, Drag it to -> Applications/Illustrator/Presets/en_GB(or en_EN)/Scripts. And then it will be in the FILE/Scripts menu forevers.

Comment: One nice thing about Illustrator's scripting (and perhaps the only thing) is that the "Other scripts" dialog remembers your last location. I keep all my Illy scripts in a Dropbox folder so I don't have to sync my multiple machines manually. Hit `cmd` + `F12` and it pulls your last scripts folder up and you can select your poison.

Comment: !!! PRO TIP !!!